# Can't get any replies to dbus-send

Tags: linux, bash, dbus, bluez

I am trying to create some scripts to discover and pair bluetooth devices on a embedded arch linux platform and seem unable to get any replies to dbus-send commands.

The error message is pretty much always the same (method does not exist), however the syntax of the send appears to be correct.

I have googled and searched here for the correct syntax and the errors, but have been unable to find any solutions.

```
[root@alarmpi ~]# dbus-send --system --dest=org.bluez --print-reply / org.bluez.Manager.GetProperties
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "GetProperties" with signature "" on interface "org.bluez.Manager" doesn't exist


[root@alarmpi ~]# dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.bluez /org/bluez/134/hci0 org.bluez.Adapter.GetProperties
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownObject: Method "GetProperties" with signature "" on interface "org.bluez.Adapter" doesn't exist
```

Bluez is installed, and I can use the hcitool and bluetoothctl utilities to manually discover and pair devices, however that method is not workable for an end-user and I need to create a web interface for them to perform the discovery and pairing.

It seems that dbus is the preferred method for doing this, as bluetoothctl does not accept command line arguments to allow it to pair a device address.

Any help / suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: hcitool does not use bluez, it directly communicates to kernel, check if bluez is running (bluetoothd) as i think bluetoothd daemon is not running

Comment: Thanks, yes it is running: [root@alarmpi ~]# ps aux | grep bluetooth
root       134  0.0  0.4   4220  1908 ?        Ss   Aug21   0:00 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Comment: 1 more check , is "sdptool browse local" gives you the o/p

Comment: Thanks - that failed: ## sdptool browse local
Failed to connect to SDP server on FF:FF:FF:00:00:00: No such file or directory ## - what does this error mean ??

Comment: this means that bluetoothd is not running, or bluetoothd is not registered to dbus.

Comment: Bluetooth daemon is definetely running and bluetooth is working perfectly, problem is I need to automate the manual command line process. How would I go about registering bluetoothd to dbus ?

Comment: I'm getting a smiliar error during boot-up on Archlinux, maybe it is a more general problem? [pulseaudio] bluetooth-util.c: org.bluez.Manager.GetProperties() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "GetProperties" with signature "" on interface "org.bluez.Manager" doesn't exist

Answer (score 4):

1. Verify that `bluetoothd` is running,
2. Install a program called `d-feet` which is a D-Bus debugger and see if the `org.bluez` is present on the system bus tab,
3. If it is navigate to the destination Object, Interface and Method which is "`/`", "org.bluez.Manager" and "`GetProperties`" respectively,
4. Double click the method name (`GetProperties`) and click execute without any arguments
5. The output should be something like `{u'Adapters': ['/org/bluez/709/hci0']}`, if it's not - you have a problem with your bluetoothd,

Btw. your command is correct.